# Background check employment verification

Tags: background-check

I have a couple of questions about employment verification in my background check.  The background check company is HireRight.  On my resume and application I put down that I worked at my last job from 08/2012 to 09/2014.  This is correct.  However the first two months I was employed there I was a temp.  I did not put the temp time on my application and resume and did not even think about it until I filled out the online information for HireRight's background check.  Additionally the title I put down for the job was technically "Machine Operator", but I put "CNC Machine Operator", which is what I did.  I ran CNC machines.  I am wondering if these small discrepancies will disqualify me for the job that I have been offered, which is in the same field.  Thank you for any helpful comments.

Comment: Oh, and I corrected the discrepancies when I filled out the information for HireRight.

Comment: You are giving yourself nightmares over trivia.

Comment: Very true brother (or sister?), well said.  Passed background and start work on the 20th.

Answer (score 4):

They shouldn't matter - you did work there, regardless of whether it was temporary or not, and you did operate CNC machines. They might flag up the discrepancies, but anyone reading it will quickly dismiss the did fences as mere detail.

Comment: Agreed. The CNC Machine Operator is a more focused title. If the temp work done was also Machine Operator work, there's no use re-stating it because you didn't stop working when transition from temp to full employment.

Comment: You are both correct.  I just filled out my I-9 and my first day is the 20th.  Just so I don't have to go through the stress again, I will modify my resume to reflect both the title, and the time I spent as a temp.  I hope this thread helps prospective employees.  = )